# Python word count and rank

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a word occurrence count application in a Python 3.2 / Windows environment.

Can anyone please help to tell me why the following isn't working?

```
from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter

N = 100
words = {}

words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in open("poi_run.txt")
                                         for word in line.split())

for word in words_gen:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

top_words = (words.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print ("%s %d") % (word, frequency)
```

The trace back error is:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Users\will\Desktop\word_count.py 13      
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Thanks

n.b.

Fully working code:

```
from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter

N = 100
words = {}

words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in open("poi_run.txt")
                                         for word in line.split())

for word in words_gen:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

top_words = sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print ("%s %d" % (word, frequency))
```

Thanks again guys

Comment: `top_words = (words.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]` - aren't you missing some function name here?

Comment: You might want to use a `defaultdict`: `words = defaultdict(int); for words in word_gen: words[word] += 1`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Actually, `Counter` from the same module is better here. Perfect, even. Why didn't I think of it before? Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @PetrViktorin: Of course. I always forget `Counter`. Much better. But it seems we've already lost him to Perl (shudder). Well, it's more his loss than ours :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, use just `items` where you'd previously use `iteritems`.

The new [`items()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns a [dictionary view object](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) that supports iteration as well as `len` and `in`.

And of course, in `top_words = (words.iteritems(), ...` you forgot to call the `sorted` function.

---

Edit: Please see my other answer for a better solution.

Comment: Wow thanks Petr, just to clarify, how would I call the sorted function?

sorted(top_words = (words.items(), key=items(1), reverse=True))[:N]

?

Comment: `top_words = sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]`

Comment: Petr cant thank you enough!! For everyones benefit final code is:

from string import punctuation
from operator import itemgetter

N = 100
words = {}

words_gen = (word.strip(punctuation).lower() for line in open("poi_run.txt")
                                             for word in line.split())

for word in words_gen:
    words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1

top_words = sorted(words.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:N]

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print ("%s %d" % (word, frequency))

Comment: Code doesn't work so well in comments, but you can edit my answer and put the code there. But, please see my other answer for an even better solution – sorry I didn't think of it before.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the `collections` module – it will do your first `for` loop for you:

```
from collections import Counter

N = 100
words_gen = ...

top_words = Counter(words_gen).most_common(N)

for word, frequency in top_words:
    print("%s %d" % (word, frequency))
```

Comment: I like this...

I'll let you know how I get on!!

Answer (score 2):

From Python 3.x [implementation documents](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

> "Also, the dict.iterkeys(), dict.iteritems() and dict.itervalues()
>   methods are no longer supported."

See the link above to actually get the correct API for 3.x

The easiest way is to use map() or filter() to get iteration keys.

Comment: Thanks for this guys.  I'm moving to Perl !!